# Angular 5 - can we do sorting for a table column and show the icon along it (for unsorting)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a table and have activated the sort headers using material angular. Can i sort by any of the column initially and show the unsorting icon, which normally comes after the column name click, along with he initially sorted icon.

For eg.; I have a table with column A,B,C,D. I want to sort the table by column C. And I want the sorted icon active initially (on component load itself).So when I click on the icon it unsorts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort Date/Time column in angular 4 material sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506984/how-to-sort-date-time-column-in-angular-4-material-sort)

Comment: No, I want to sort the table based on a column and show the icon to unsort it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can initially sort a a column. Check out [MatSort](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/api#MatSort) and its `sort` function.

All you need to do in your component is the following:

```
// Reference the matSort which you should already have anyway
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
  // Link the sort to the table and then sort it initially
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.sort.sort({disableClear: false, id: 'progress', start: 'desc'});
}
```

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-stpdss?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz where I have taken one of the Angular Material
>   examples and added an initial sort on the column `progress`.

Comment: It sorts alright, but the sorting icon (up / down  arrow) is not completing the animation initially (shows as a T)